import torchtext - OSError: [WinError 127]
I'm trying to run a Test.py with 'import torchtext' in it.
it throws this error:
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\Test.py", line 10, in <module>
     import torchtext   File "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torchtext\__init__.py",
 line 18, in <module>
     from torchtext import _extension  # noqa: F401
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torchtext\_extension.py",
 line 64, in <module>
     _init_extension()   File "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torchtext\_extension.py",
 line 58, in _init_extension
     _load_lib("libtorchtext")   File "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torchtext\_extension.py",
 line 50, in _load_lib
     torch.ops.load_library(path)   File "C:\Users\anryu\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py",
 line 1295, in load_library
     ctypes.CDLL(path)   File "C:\Users\anryu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py",
 line 379, in __init__
     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ OSError: [WinError 127] The specifiedj procedure could not be found

I'm running on cpu. I'm using python 3.12, torch 2.4.0 and torchtext 0.18.0, which should be compatible.
I tried installing different python & pytorch versions but it didnt help.
Rerunning just throws the same error. No forums I've found say anything helpful either.

I've solved the problem for myself. I just needed to downgrade to torch - 2.2.2, torchtext - 0.17.2 and numpy - 1.26.4.

Yeah , same fix for me - downgrade torchtext to 0.17.2 and Torch to 2.2.1 + downgrade to Python 3.9 ( from 3.10 )
